# Why is ie7 ignoring the left-margin on my first list item (only)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, margin, listitem

http://blog.helpcurenow.org/test/mockups/mar2010/lp.html

In the above landing page, I have an offers box that has four donation buttons. The first three are targeted with individual id's and given a left margin of 13px.

All is well in every browser I'm viewing in except ie7. For some reason ie7 is ignoring the left-margin of 13px on the first list item, and only on that one.

The strange part is when I open ie's developer tools (not actually viewing in ie7, but using ie8 in ie7 mode) and select the element, it shows that the 13px margin is there, and not crossed out. The browser just seems to be ignoring it!

Is there some ie7 quirk I should know about here or did I miss a CSS declaration I should have added? Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: I think what he's saying is that the real Internet Explorer 7 doesn't behave exactly like IE8 running in compatibility/IE7 mode, which may be true, but is completely irrelevant to your question. Your problem is exhibited in IE8's compatibility view. I've spent a few minutes investigating, and I too cannot explain why it's happening. I may be able to suggest a solution, though. Stand by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the padding on the `ul` that houses those `li`s to `10px 13px`, then remove the `margin-left` from the `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the wrong borders,  line-heights and box-models and you are safe.

in the top first line of your CSS, you just add:

```
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,li,img {border:none;padding:0;margin:0; /* etc. like font-size:10px;line-height:10px; */}
```

then you can set the "wanted" values on each item afterwards:
further more you can set

```
display:block;
```

on your elements then they will use the same box-model. IE6/IE7 does not understand inline-block which is default for some elements I believe.