# CSS - IE7 ignoring margin on first list item?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

If you go to the first blog item (Mona) and expand it using the '+' icon. The image thumbnails are aligned 24px from the left using a margin. This works in every browser but IE7 which ignores the margin on the first list item.

http://www.dririser.co.uk/index.php

**CSS**

```
.artistMeta li {
float: left;
margin: 0 0 24px 24px;
position: relative;
width: 160px;
}
```

There is a similar question on here but the there was no real answer and I can't use their solution.

[Why is ie7 ignoring the left-margin on my first list item (only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372799/why-is-ie7-ignoring-the-left-margin-on-my-first-list-item-only)

Any ideas?

Comment: Presently i have no IE7 at hand, but it sounds to me like one of the hasLayout bugs. Hence I recommend to check http://haslayout.net/css/ where you probably find a solution or may be directed towards one.

Comment: it actually ignores it on the second `li` only..

Comment: It is usually the first, I had to add a class back in with jQuery as the projects about to go live, but the issue is still the same, there is now just a specific class for the first list item. Problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick test.. not sure if it will work.. but try adding a `display:block` on your `li` and don't use the shorthand for the margin, instead use `margin-left` and `margin-bottom`... 
it seems to me that IE is not refreshing the style of the elements, because when i inspect the elements, the navigator adds the correct margins...

If that doesn't work.. you might want to put the style inside the tag (since you're using JS to add the images), i know it's not elegant, but i guess that could force the navigator to set the style on the `li`

and if that doesn't work.. then i've no idea what could be wrong =P. I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, didn't do anything though. I've never come across a browser not being able to interpret CSS shorthand before?

Answer (score 0):

<del>The problem IE7 is having here isn't in your CSS file, it's in your javascript in **global.js**. Specifically the following line ...</del>

```
$(".artistMeta > li:nth-child(3n+1)").addClass("articleSlideOdd");
```

As per the convention in CSS, JQuery starts the child count at 1 for *nth-child* (as in the first child is `nth-child(1)`), where as, ie7 is expecting it to start at 0. So with ie7 *3n+1* matches the 2nd, 5th, 8th item and so on.

Looks like JQuery isn't handling ie7 properly, so you'll need two statements to cover ie7, and everything else.

Comment: Are you sure? I did a test fiddle and it seems to work correctly in IE7 etc http://jsfiddle.net/sSwsw/

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong. I thought it was like that because if you change the margin-left in `articleSlideOdd` to say 5px, in IE7 it's the second one that gets shifted by 5px (i.e. unexpected behaviour). However if, in the same css block, you add a border, it's the first one that gets the border *(which is expected behaviour, and I guess proves me wrong)*.

Comment: In IE8 you get the same behaviour under IE7 mode, but whats bizarre is that as soon as you click on any of the CSS checkboxes in the IE8 Developer Tools, the image positions get automatically corrected. I think you've just come across a browser bug.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I appreciate it. Still can't fix it!